# Error en algoritmo de grafos bipartitos

Tags: c, teoría-de-grafos

Tengo que determinar si un grafo es o no bipartito. A veces anda bien en algunos grafos, pero hay dos específicamente que NO son bipartitos pero que dan que SÍ lo son. Son bastantes grandes esos grafos.

Bipartito:

- Devuelve 1 si G es bipartito, 0 si no.
- Si es bipartito, deja a G coloreado en forma propia con los colores 0 y 1.
- Si devuelve 0, antes debe colorear a G con Greedy, en algún orden.

Acá voy a poner el código de bipartito, y sus respectivas estructuras, para ver si encuentran algún error.

No podría ponerles qué grafo anda mal porque son muy grandes, y para la toma de grafos tengo mucho más código.

Capaz me la estoy complicando de más con algunas cosas y no me estoy dando cuenta, no lo sé.

```c
typedef unsigned int u32; 

typedef struct GrafoSt
{
   u32** vecinos;
   u32* vertices;  // Posicion de los vertices
   u32* color; //Structure type declarations do not support initializers
   u32* grados;
   u32* orden; //it has the index of the vertex array not the name of vertex
   u32* visitados;
   u32 m; //number of edges
   u32 n; // number of vertex
   u32 max; // number of colors
   u32* indEnVecinos;
} GrafoSt;


int Bipartito(Grafo G)
{
   assert(G != NULL);
   u32* visitados = G->visitados;
   u32** aux = G->vecinos;
   Queue* hijos = init_queue();
   push(hijos,G->vertices[0]);
   u32 nVer = G->n;
   u32* color_vertices = (u32*)calloc(nVer, sizeof(u32));
   u32* vert_encolados = (u32*)calloc(nVer, sizeof(u32));
   memset(visitados,0,nVer*sizeof(u32));
   u32* bip = (u32*)calloc(2, sizeof(u32));
   bip[0] = 0;
   bip[1] = 0;
   u32 indice2 = 0;
   while(not_empty(hijos))
   {
       u32 v = hijos->front->data;
       pop(hijos);
       u32 indice = binarySearch(G->vertices,0,nVer-1,v);
       visitados[indice] = 1;
       for (u32 j = 0; j < G->grados[indice]; ++j)
       {
           indice2 = binarySearch(G->vertices,0,nVer-1,aux[G->indEnVecinos[indice]+j][1]);
           if(G->visitados[indice2])
           {
               bip[color_vertices[indice2]] = 1;
               if(bip[0] && bip[1])
               {
                   while(not_empty(hijos))
                   {
                       pop(hijos);
                   }
                   free(hijos);
                   free(color_vertices);
                   free(bip);
                   free(vert_encolados);
                   return 0;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               if(!vert_encolados[indice2])
               {
                   push(hijos, G->vertices[indice2]);
                   vert_encolados[indice2] = 1;
               }
           }
       }
       for (u32 j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
       {
           if(!bip[j])
           {
               color_vertices[indice] = j;
           }
       }
       memset(bip,0,2*sizeof(u32));
   }
   free(hijos);
   memcpy(G->color,color_vertices,nVer*sizeof(u32));
   free(color_vertices);
   free(bip);
   free(vert_encolados);
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué condición debe cumplir un grafo para ser bipartito?

Comment: Que se pueda colorear con 2 colores. Los vertices se podrían separar en dos conjuntos disjuntos. Todo un conjunto sería coloreado con un color, y todo el otro con otro color.

Comment: Esa descripción no me ayuda. ¿Qué condición debe cumplir un grafo para ser bipartito? **en el contexto de programación** no en contexto teórico.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bipartite-graph/ .. Mmm, no se si te referís a eso, creo que lo más cerca que encontré es esto.

Comment: "*En un grafo bipartido cada vértice puede clasificarse en dos conjuntos independientes. Se puede decir que no hay conexiones dentro del mismo conjunto*". ¿Es eso correcto?

Comment: Efectivamente. Tiene que ser así. Sino, si hubiese una conexión dentro de un mismo conjunto tendría que estar coloreado con un tercer color, y ya no sería bipartito